Logarithm - Transferring properties of a Sum to an Integral
I stumbled across the expression $\sum_k \ln a_k = \ln \prod_k a_k$
I know, it originates in the properties of the logarithm. The expression is sometimes handy to pull the logarithm out of a sum while transforming the summation into a product.
I am wondering, if there is a similar expression regarding integration where you can pull the logarithm in front without solving the integral. I am wondering, as integration can be defined as a sum with the step size approaching 0.
I know $$\int  \ln x \, \mathrm{d}x =C -x  + x \ln x = C + \ln  \left( x^x e^{-x} \right)$$
or
$$\int_a^b \ln x \, \mathrm{d}x =
\ln \left( \frac{b^b}{a^a} e^{a-b} \right)$$
These expressions move the logarithm in front, but it is not what I am looking for.
Is there a general expression for $\int_a^b  \ln f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $?

There is an analogous relation for integration, but you need to define a product integral (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_II:_Geometric_integral).

Note: This post answers the question given initially about the transference of the identity $\sum_k \ln(a_k) = \ln \prod_k a_k$ to the continuous case. It does not answer the later-added question about a general form for the integral $\int_a^b \ln f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$; to my knowledge, no meaningful form exists for general $f$.

Yes. The idea takes the origin in the geometric integral, for which the identity
$$
\mathcal{G}\!\!\int_a^b f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x} = \exp \left( \mathcal{R}\!\!\int_a^b \ln (f(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)
$$
holds for "suitably nice" functions. (Here,  I am distinguishing the geometric integral with a $\mathcal{G}$ and the ordinary Riemann integral with a $\mathcal{R}$.)
We can formalize the geometric integral by way of
$$
\mathcal{G}\!\!\int_a^b f(x)^{\mathrm{d}x} 
:= \lim_{\|P\| \to 0} \prod_i f(\xi_i)^{\Delta x_i}
$$
with the usual definitions for the partition points $P := \{x_i\}$ and the intermediate tags $\Xi := \{\xi_i\}$. (Read more here if those details matter somewhat, but it's just a natural extension of the same rationale as for ordinary integrals.)
Then your question becomes: is $\ln x$ a function such that the $\mathcal{R}$-integral of $\ln x$ equals the logarithm of the $\mathcal{G}$-integral of $x$, i.e.
$$\newcommand{\Rint}{\mathcal{R}\!\!\int}
\newcommand{\Gint}{\mathcal{G}\!\!\int}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\Rint_a^b \ln(x) \, \dd x
\stackrel{?}{=}
\ln \left( \Gint_a^b x^{\dd x} \right)
$$
Using the identity given initially, this is trivially true.

This is not the only way to generalize the integral in the sense of turning sums to products; the Wikipedia article on the product integral covers three. The above I've defined seems to be the most commonly used, at least in what I've seen, but others might know better. Your mileage may vary with the other types of integrals.
